# Estimate probability that element in the constructed set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let build a set A by this rule: for $i$ from $0$ to $n - 1$ with probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ we add this number to set $A$. It's some kind Bernoulli distribution, as I understood. 
Then we generate set $B = A - A = \{a_1 - a_2: a \in A, a_2 \in A\}$

And the question is to find upper boun on probability $P(k \notin B)$ as precise as possible.

My idea: 1) If k > 0 we can built our number $2(n - 1) - k$ ways

2) $k < 0 => 2(n - 1) + k$

Totally: there are $(2(n - 1) - |k|)$ ways how we can get our number as $a_1 - a_2$.

The probability of each event is $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

Total probability could be counted by inclusion–exclusion principle:
$$P(k \in B) = \frac{1}{4} \binom{2(n - 1) - |k|}{1} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4} \binom{2(n - 1) - |k|}{2} + \cdots = \text{ ?}$$

And at this step I stuck.

Could you check my half-solution and help with estimating upper bound of $P( k \notin B)$?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It already appeared today as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556963/estimate-the-upper-bound-of-probability/1557069?noredirect=1#comment3170440_1557069

Comment: It's a task from our professor. It's a number of tasks, but it's one of the most difficult and a deadline is today at midnight:(